# Travis CI: line 57 error: pytest#: command not found

Tags: python-3.x, travis-ci, pytest

I am trying to setup Travis CI for my project
https://github.com/openmodal/lvm_read

the .travis file is:

```
language: python
python:
 - "3.5"
install: "pip install -r requirements.txt"
script:
  - pytest# py.test also does not work
```

I follow the Travis CI tutorila, but I do not know what am I doing wrong.

I get the following error:

> /home/travis/build.sh: line 57: pytest#: command not found

I hope you can help me; please check the repo above if you require details.

PS: pytest works fine in my local virtualenv

Comment: Could you show the contents of requirements.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be interpreting the `#` as part of the command on `pytest#`.

Try adding a space before or remove the comment.

Comment: Thank you; I guess I would never figured out this "bug"!